# How to define more layouts for subdirectories in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have the main layout that wraps whole app:

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}
```

I want to have the main layout and another layout to wrap, for example `localhost:3000/subdirectory/...` subdirectory.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts

Comment: @spatialaustin I don't think it's possible with the document you provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply like below:

**First, remove the layout from your _app.js**

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}
```

**Second, create you first layout component:**

```
const MainLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <main>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
};

export default MainLayout;
```

**Then Second layout:**

```
  const Dashboard = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <main>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard ;
```

**Then you can import your layout and use it like in your component:**

```
import Dashboard from './Dashboard ';
export default function Card(){
  return(
     <Dashboard><div>your code</div><Dashboard>
  )
}
```

**And:**

```
import MainLayoutfrom './MainLayout';
export default function Card(){
  return(
     <MainLayout><div>your code</div><MainLayout>
  )
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a layout in a component if you intend to use that same layout for many different components. The whole point of using the same wrapper for everything is to abstract out that code which is repeated in many different files. So, with that said, I don't think this is a particularly clean soultion